# Trying to use ipget

Tags: github, ipfs

I've installed ipget from this github repo: https://github.com/ipfs/ipget. I have followed all steps, i.e.:

```
go get -d github.com/ipfs/ipgete
cd ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/ipfs/ipget
make install
```

I now try to run the following command:

```
ipget 
QmQ2r6iMNpky5f1m4cnm3Yqw8VSvjuKpTcK1X7dBR1LkJF/cat.gif -o nyan.gif
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
zsh: command not found: ipget
```

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is your `${GOPATH}/bin` in the system `PATH`?

Answer (score -1):

If command is not found you don't have ipget installed yet. Try installing it by downloading a binary from here: https://dist.ipfs.io/#ipget